# HLS AVPlayer on iOS - return to live

Tags: ios, live, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I have an AVPlayer which is streaming a live HLS stream.

When the user multitasks the app, I see the play rate drop to 0.0 (paused), when the user comes back it return to 1.0(play), but starts playing from the point it was paused.

What is the best way to force the player back to live without restarting the stream completely? Is there a seekToTime method that handles a closest to live time parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I use:

```
 double time = MAXFLOAT;
 [player seekToTime: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, NSEC_PER_SEC)];
```

Works well in my app.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming player is an AVPlayer instance:

```
CMTimeRange seekableRange = [player.currentItem.seekableTimeRanges.lastObject CMTimeRangeValue];
CGFloat seekableStart = CMTimeGetSeconds(seekableRange.start);
CGFloat seekableDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(seekableRange.duration);
CGFloat livePosition = seekableStart + seekableDuration;

[player seekToTime:CMTimeMake(livePosition, 1)];
```

Comment: This is the real answer. Worked for me like a charm.

Comment: You can also use CMTimeAdd instead of converting to floating point

Comment: You can also use CMTimeRangeGetEnd instead of adding the duration to the start.

Comment: When you wait long enough this solution leads to exceptions because the time is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

Swift version of [Igor Kulagin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13892727/7641654) answer:

```
player.seek(to: kCMTimePositiveInfinity)
player.play()
```

Works perfectly in any condition. Other solutions gave me `NaN` error calculating `livePosition` value, or `{INVALID}` error working directly with `CMTime`.

Comment: on iOS 14 this doesn't seem to work anymore, had to use the seekableTimeRanges solution

Comment: This works good for me on iOS 14+.

Comment: If you wait long time (few minutes), the return to play is long (few minutes). For short stop it works well. (iOS 16)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0 Version

```
public func resumeLive() {
    guard let livePosition = player.currentItem?.seekableTimeRanges.last as? CMTimeRange else {
        return
    }
    player.seek(to:CMTimeRangeGetEnd(livePosition))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of Karim Mourra's answer:

```
let seekableRanges = player.currentItem!.seekableTimeRanges
guard seekableRanges.count > 0 else {
  return
}

let range = seekableRanges.last!.CMTimeRangeValue
let livePosition = range.start + range.duration

let minus = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(timeOffset), Int32(NSEC_PER_SEC))
let time = livePosition - minus

player.seekToTime(time)
```

Comment: guard let lastRange = player.currentItem?.seekableRanges.last else {

    return;

}


player.seekToTime(lastRange.end)

Comment: what's "timeoffset"?

Comment: @HongZhou it's a completely optional buffer in seconds. You can just use `livePosition` and omit the line with `timeOffset`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert to floating point if you use Apple's `CMTimeRange` manipulation functions:

```
NSValue *value = player.currentItem.seekableTimeRanges.lastObject;
if (value) {
    CMTimeRange seekableRange = [value CMTimeRangeValue];
    CMTime latestTime = CMTimeRangeGetEnd(seekableRange);
    [player seekToTime:latestTime];
} else {
    // there are no seekable time ranges
}
```

Please see [@Fabian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145048/hls-avplayer-on-ios-return-to-live/36317122#comment65730880_36317122) below.

Comment: No need to add time if you use CMTimeRangeGetEnd

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version:

```
if let seekableRange = player.currentItem?.seekableTimeRanges.last?.timeRangeValue {
    let seekableStart = seekableRange.start
    let seekableDuration = seekableRange.duration
    let livePosition = seekableStart + seekableDuration

    player.seek(to: livePosition, completionHandler: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.player.play()
    })
}
```

Comment: It produces excpetions when you wait long time because time is not valid.